# How to implement my own backup agent in android

Tags: android, android-backup-service, backup-agent

I know there's the Android class BackupAgent class which allow users to backup and restore only their own apps data. However, I'm looking for a way to take over the Android's default backup and restore functionality and allow a user to choose a different cloud storage for data backing up and restoration. Furthermore, I need to backup all the stored data in the device.